# Codeigniter with MongoDB sub array

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have below type of collection in mongodb:

```
Array
(
[_id] => 4fcf383a5990581c0b000015
[user_id] => 1
[username] => admin
[password] => 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
[first_name] => admin
[last_name] => admin
[address] => 
[address_2] => 
 [deshboard_report] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [report_ids] => 1
                [rpt_color] => color-red
                [rpt_status] => max
                [report_title] => Last Point
                [report_file] => last_location
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [report_ids] => 2
                [rpt_color] => color-green
                [rpt_status] => max
                [report_title] => Inactive Device
                [report_file] => inactive_devices
            )
    )
)
```

I want to search in `report_ids` and that search return sub array of `deshboard_report` how it is possible?

I use this library to connect: https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library

Comment: just for reference the same question has been asked here as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/NRsk8frOm0U

Answer (score 1):

When querying for an element in an array, your results will currently return the whole document by default.

You can return whole documents matching subarrays with specific report_ids using $elemMatch.

Example for the JS shell .. find documents with report_ids=2 :

```
  db.collection.find({'deshboard_report': {"$elemMatch": {report_ids: 2}}});
```